# Форматирование шрифта в тексте на точке Google maps

Tags: joomla, google-maps-api

Доброе время суток. Просьба помочь с данной проблемой. Имеется карта `Google maps` с одной отметкой. Но шрифт на белом фоне белый. Никак не могу найти информацию по редактированию шрифта. Нужно изменить размер шрифта и цвет.

P.S.: На скрине текст выделен мышкой. Сайт на `Joomla`, подключаю карты через плагин `Googlemap`. В настройках плагина ничего такого не нашел.

Заранее спасибо.

[image]

Comment: Разве никто не может помочь?((

Comment: @jkwe45, предполагаю, что причина в накладываемых на baloon стилях. Проверьте через dev-панель браузера (правой кнопкой на тексте - проверить элемент, раздел css) или дайте ссылку на страницу, на которой можно вживую посмотреть